# Selenium send_keys not working on wappalyzer?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using Selenium to automate searching on wappalyzer.com. Below is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

def handleWappalyzer(driver):
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class*='v-select__selections']").click()

    search = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class*='v-text-field__slot'] > input[type='text']")
    search.send_keys("https://www.facebook.com//")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver.get("https://www.wappalyzer.com/")

    handleWappalyzer(driver)

    driver.quit()
```

However, whenever I run the script, the key is not getting written in the search bar. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Warrier
The locator you have provided for `search` looks incorrect.

Can you try this `"#input-360"`

Also, add some wait before it.